# How do topologists count infinite dimensional holes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

For example, it seems like there "should" be an infinite dimensional hole (or perhaps many) in $S^1 \times  S^1 \times \ldots$. (Or perhaps none...) Is there an invariant that would count it? What sort of "interesting" spaces motivate the study of such invariants? Non-finite topological vector spaces minus a point?

Googling infinite dimensional homotopy groups and infinite dimensional homology groups didn't turn up anything that seemed relevant.

Comment: The infinite dimensional sphere is contractible, so $[S^\infty, X]$ is always trivial. (Although this doesn't fully answer your questions.) In the $\Pi S^1$ example, it seems to me that you only have a large $\pi_1$ group.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by an "infinite dimensional hole". I do know however that an infinite dimensional Hilbert space minus a point is contractible. Thus, it has no holes (finite dimensional or not).

Comment: @user119629, for the $\Pi S^1$ case I was thinking in particular of homology, rather than homotopy.

Comment: @user1119629 No, that's not true. Consider the second homology of $S^1 \times S^1$. Only for homotopy groups is it multiplicative. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem

Comment: @user1119629 No problem. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A problem with extending homotopy and homology groups to the infinite dimensional case is that the infinite dimensional sphere $S^\infty=\cup_{n} S^n$ (where each $S^n$ includes in $S^{n+1}$ equatorially) is contractible. An easy way to see this is Whitehead's theorem. All homotopy groups vanish, so it must be contractible. Maybe there is some other way to generalize homology or homotopy groups, but the naive way fails.

Here's another example that indicates things are strange when you go to infinite dimensions. The Hilbert cube is the infinite product of closed intervals which you can think of as getting smaller and smaller in diameter. The weird thing is that it is homogeneous. There is a self-homeomorphism taking any point to any point. So, even though it feels like it has a well-defined boundary, it doesn't. In particular taking a point away from it will not change its homotopy type!

Comment: How does it follow that removing a point does not change it's homotopy type? $R^n$ is also homogeneous, but it doesn't share that property. (The homotopy type is the class of homotopy equivalent spaces?)

Comment: @user54092: Because removing it from what feels like the boundary will obviously not change its homotopy type.

Comment: Just in the way that removing a point from the boundary of a manifold doesn't change it's homotopy type?

Comment: @user54092: yes.